# Getting PY_VAR1 when i print 'query'

Tags: python, tkinter, web-scraping

Im making a simple web scrape code and when i try to print a value it gives me something else.

```
def PeopleSearch():
query = SearchTerm
query = ('what is '+ query)
print str(query)


SearchTerm = StringVar(None)
SearchText = Entry(app, textvariable=SearchTerm)
SearchText.pack()
```

'SearchTerm' is gotten from a text Box. If i try to print str(query)
i get PY_VAR1. And i get PY_VAR1 no matter what i type.

But this only happens when i do it from program containing tkinter module. Without GUI, it prints exactly what i typed in.

What is up? Huh?

Answer (score 3):

StringVar is an object which *manages* the value - to get the value itself you want SearchTerm.get()